# Webservice won't accept JSON requests

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, plesk

The main issue is that I cannot  run a webservice that accepts requests in JSON format.  I keep getting a 500 Server error stating that the "request format is invalid."  My ASP.NET AJAX extensions are installed.  My server is running Plesk Control Panel 8.6 which is undoubtedly causing these problems.

The default handler for this specified extension is shown in the web.config  like so:

For my applications webservice to handle JSON it needs to have this reference:

```
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Plesk is not allowing the request to be handled properly.  I need to know the correct http directive(s) to put into the web.config to properly handle JSON webservices.  I tried posting to the Plesk forum two days ago but no response yet.

Any insight would be great =)

Answer (score 0):

There are confirmed errors with webservices and httphandlers.  To avoid grief, upgrade to > Plesk 9.0.